# R - How to compare values across more than two columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to write code to compare the values of several columns, and i dont know ahead of time how many columns I will have. The data will look like this:

```
X   Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4
A   1        1        1       2
B   NA       2        2       2
C   3        3        3       3
```

The code should return a Fail for rows A and B, and a Pass for row C, but needs to be able to handle a changing number of columns. I can't figure out how to do this without nesting a couple of for loops, but there has to be some way to use apply or sapply to iterate through columns 2: length(df)

EDIT: I want to see if the values (which will be numbers) are equal

Comment: What comparison are you doing ?

Comment: Just seeing if the values are the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the first column is excluded from the comparison and that all the other columns are not, you can try:

```
which(rowSums(df[,2]==df[,3:ncol(df)])==(ncol(df)-2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` with a custom function `length(unique(x))` to count the unique number of values in rows `2:ncol(yourDataFrame)`. You can then throw the whole thing into an `ifelse` function to return a true/false list.

```
ifelse(apply(df[ , 2:ncol(yourDataFrame)], MARGIN=1, function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: This works if all the values are exactly the same, but is there a way to make it actually compare  values? i.e. I believe 4 and 4.00 would return a false negative here.

Comment: @user3711502 I think R drops trailing zeros for any numeric fields, so this function would return TRUE for a row with (4, 4.00), for example, even if the first column is an integer and the second is numeric. We can also change the `length(unique(x))` to instead be `length(unique(as.numeric(x)))` to ensure an equal comparison.